# Octave Sublime Build

Tags: matlab, sublimetext3

How can I create a build that runs Octave for the current file in Sublime Text 3 (Mac 10.14) that prints the output in the command line or open the plot in a new window?

Comment: What is going on where you're starting a function with `else if`?

Comment: @Dason Sorry, this is an excerpt from a larger script.  I'm editing the original post now.

Comment: While you're at it can you trim it down and make it reproducible

Comment: @Dason - sure, not sure exactly how to do that with a script based off of reading an excel file, but open to suggestions!

Comment: Is reading the Excel file a necessary component of the question or could you directly make some sample data that mimics the same properties

Comment: Yes it's a necessary component because if the excel changes the code changes @Dason

Comment: But how is that related to your question about "only allow for it to be the sum of two positive numbers"?

Comment: Ok @Dason I've modified the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a`grep`statement:

```
if (length(grep("FALSE",(data_read$`Males/Trap` >= 0)))>0 &  length(grep("FALSE",(data_read$`Females/Trap` >= 0)))>0)
```

So that it would tell me if any of the values in `(data_read$`Males/Trap`>= 0)` returned false, thereby giving a number greater than `0`.

Answer (score 2):

If your datasets are not too big, you might want to complete import the file first and later on use dplyr's filter

```
dplyr::filter_at(df, c("Males/Trap","Females/Trap") , funs(. > 0))
```

(I have to say that without the dataset I can't test it, but I hope this works).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify this a lot by adding up the TRUE/FALSE statements instead of use length/grep.  I'm can't tell which direction you want to go, but one of the following lines should get you want you want:

```
if (sum(!(test3 == (tmp <- test2 + test1))) > 0 & tmp > 0) return(FALSE)
return(TRUE)
```

or

```
if (sum(!(test3 == (tmp <- test2 + test1))) > 0 | tmp < 0) return(FALSE)
return(TRUE)
```